# Bootstrap glyphicons (fonts/****.woff) not loading

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, apache, google-chrome, woff

I am an error getting that looks like this in my Google chrome(56.0.2924.87) console while trying to use bootstrap glyphicons

[image]

Even though i have my .woff files and .ttf files located in my "public/css/fonts" folder.

**Addtional Information**

I am using Wampserver with apache(2.4.23)

I installed bootstrap.css with "npm install bootstrap"

**This is what my font-face looks like**

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: italic;
  src: url('/public/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
  src: url('/public/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/public/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('/public/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('/public/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/public/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
```

}

**I try to call the glyphicons like this:**

```
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i>
```

Does anyone have any idea where this problem might be located?

Comment: "Invalid version tag", can you show your html/css? (Where you call the font and call bootstrap)

Comment: @Thomas Rbt edited with further information

Comment: @Thomas Rbt bootstrap is working fine, aside from the glyphicons

Answer (score 2):

Double check @font-face location path and also the mime type.

Comment: i am using this exact path: /public/css/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff

Comment: Could you post your webpack.config.js.

Comment: @MarcusH where would the css be located ?

Comment: im not sure i have one, the project creator is using something called "gulp" is that what you need?

Comment: the css is located in "style.css" and all the files are scss files, which is also completely new to me :)

Comment: Try and re-install the font files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139464/discussion-between-vaishal-patel-and-marcus-h).

Comment: Solved it, i had to create a folder with the font-family name