# What are those WOFF files that my BootStrap wants to see?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, npm, bootstrap-4, glyphicons

I'm a bit confused as a troubleshoot my project. When a menu folds back, I get two errors about missing resource.

> .../fontawesome-webfont.af7ae505a9eed503f8b8.woff2
>   .../fontawesome-webfont.fee66e712a8a08eef580.woff

I haven't requested them and I'm only using BootStrap (4 alpha 6) with FontAwesome 4.7, which is supposed to provide TTF file (which it does successfully as shown below.

> .../fontawesome-webfont.b06871f281fee6b241d6.ttf

When I googled the missing files, I've got some hits on GitHub but I don't want to install them because I don't understand **why** the site requests them. It seems to my like something in BootStrap is broken but I prefer not to point the blame at a professional framework (be that alpha stage but still...) and I'm fairly certain that it's something stupid I've done.

I've found [some answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111943/bootstrap-glyphicons-fonts-woff-not-loading) but those regard a case where the glyph icons are used and I haven't had problems with that (the ones that I'm using show nicely and clearly).

At the moment I'm a bit confused so I might be barking up the wrong tree...

Comment: It is common for a font-face (family) to include separate versions of the font file. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11002874/2079735

Comment: @Purgatory I see, thanks for the link. Still, googling for a few minutes on how to resolve it gave me very little. As far I understand, those are supposed to be included in the installed FontAwesome package I already have. What do I need to install more? Or am I looking at it from the wrong angle?